# How to add text to end of file via shell script which includes double quotes

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I am trying to create a simple shell script to make it easier for me to add/setup a new site within my local MAMP web development environment.  I have the following script, but the text which needs to be added to the end of of my VHOSTS.conf file contains double quotes and its throwing an error when trying to write the file. How can I add text to the end of a file when the string which needs to be appended contains double quotes?

```
clear

echo "Enter the name of the dev site you want to add (ie: mysite.dev): "
read devname
echo "Enter the name of the directory where your site lives (ie: /Volumes/Clients/AIA/Website/Dev/): "
read directory
echo "$directory is what you typed in. Your record will be added"

echo '<VirtualHost *:8888>
ServerName $devname
DocumentRoot "$directory"
<Directory "$direcotry">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>' >> /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/vhosts.conf

echo ""
echo "Your record has successfully been added for $devname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable interpolation doesn't work inside single quotes. You could use double quotes and then escape the quotes inside the string with `\"`.

```
echo "<VirtualHost *:8888>
ServerName $devname
DocumentRoot \"$directory\"
<Directory \"$directory\">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>" >> /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/vhosts.conf
```

Alternatively, for long multi-line strings you might prefer heredoc syntax. You can delimit a long string with `<<TOKEN` at the beginning and `TOKEN` at the end, where `TOKEN` is some arbitrary word. It lets you use single and double quotes freely without having to escape them.

Heredocs are passed on stdin rather than on the command-line so you'd also switch the `echo` to a `cat`.

```
cat >> /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/vhosts.conf <<CONF
<VirtualHost *:8888>
ServerName $devname
DocumentRoot "$directory"
<Directory "$directory">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
CONF
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables need to be placed around double quotes in order for them to be expanded. You also simply have to quote them with instances of double quotes inside it with `\` i.e. `\"`.

```
echo "<VirtualHost *:8888>
ServerName $devname
DocumentRoot \"$directory\"
<Directory \"$direcotry\">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>" >> /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/vhosts.conf
```